# What is bogus_type in C

Tags: c, gcc, types

I've been going through some types defined in libgcc. They are all apparently mapped to the same type named `bogus_type`. I can not find its definition.

```
#define SItype bogus_type
#define USItype bogus_type
#define DItype bogus_type
#define UDItype bogus_type
#define SFtype bogus_type
#define DFtype bogus_type
```

What does this type map to? Is it even a valid type or something like `NULL`?

Answer (score 4):

[Here's another example](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/7c62dfbbcd3699efcbbadc9fb3aa14f23a123add/libgcc/libgcc2.h#L156) of this "type" being used.

```
/* Make sure that we don't accidentally use any normal C language built-in
   type names in the first part of this file.  Instead we want to use *only*
   the type names defined above.  The following macro definitions insure
   that if we *do* accidentally use some normal C language built-in type name,
   we will get a syntax error.  */

#define char bogus_type
#define short bogus_type
#define int bogus_type
#define long bogus_type
#define unsigned bogus_type
#define float bogus_type
#define double bogus_type
```

That said, **it's not a type. It's a legitimate code breaker to enforce the restriction on using certain types** in certain places of the program. Should it fire, compilation should fail with a syntax error, since `bogus_type` does not exist.

It's not any "less-than-known" part of the language, it's just clever use of the C preprocessor.

Comment: Fortunately the compiler does not mind the [mangling of English syntax](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/433/when-i-should-use-assure-vs-ensure-vs-insure) in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It is put before some code that *should not* accidentally use one of these types later on. So if it is using one of these, the compiler would throw an error, since there is no such a `bogus_type` type.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `define` is just a text replacement that take place before the compilation phase, as long as no one will use the defined type, there be no replacement to `bogus_type` and nothing will happen. If someone will use those types, they will be replaced with `bogus_type` which is in fact not defined anywhere which will make the compilation to failed.

so basically `bogus_type` is just a rabbis that is used to forcely failed the build in case of a use in a specific type. For the sake of it, it could be:

```
#define SItype you_are_using_a_type_you_should_not_be_using!
```